# Polygons are not splitting across the international dateline as expected in R using sf st_wrap_dateline

Tags: r, geospatial, polygon, r-sf

I have polygons that cross the dateline, however are instead inverting and wrapping away from the dataline.

As an example the code here should produce a complete hex grid of 122 cells and break on the dateline. My thinking has been that st_wrap_dateline should cause the inverted polygons to split by inserting a line along the dateline and create multiple polygons. I'm not sure what next to try.

Code and output below.

Any assistance would be most appreciated.

```
install.packages("h3jsr")
install.packages("sf")

library("h3jsr")
library("sf")


# Make number sequence
pts  = as.data.frame(merge(seq (-90,90,1),seq (0,360,1),all=TRUE))
colnames(pts) <- c("LAT","LON")

pts_ <- st_as_sf(x = pts, coords = c("LON","LAT"),crs = 4326)

# resolve H3 index at Resolution
pts_H3 <- point_to_h3(pts_, res = 0, simple = FALSE)

pts_H3 <- as.data.frame(table(pts_H3$h3_resolution_0))

getH3_Poly <- h3_to_polygon(pts_H3$Var1,simple=FALSE)

# timeline wrap
getH3_Poly <- st_wrap_dateline(getH3_Poly, options = c("WRAPDATELINE=YES"))
plot(getH3_Poly)
```

[image: The image is produced from plot - and shows how the polygon inverts]

Comment: Any difference if you `c(WRAPDATELINE=YES, DATELINEOFFSET='?')`, the ? in dataline offset regards default of 10 vs your hexagon of ?. Though my weak thinking is you are in [this unresolved dateline hell](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1862), or perhaps the previously addressed mentioned in `st_wrap_dateline` (issues 280, 541) help. I guess next I'd read the st_wrap_dateline code and see if it is doing the split polygon, st_combine, st_make valid...Most cases I've read deal with lines, so perhaps this is an `sf` use case report.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/794450/chris Thanks for taking the time. Not sure how to make ? work as they are not regular... I think the best thing to do will be to union a vector dateline to the hexagons and see if I can solve it brutally that way. Will paste code if I can get it to behave.

Comment: What's your bbox of getH3_poly, prior to call to st_wrap_dateline? mine `Bounding box:  xmin: -179.6744 ymin: -87.3647 xmax: 145.2416 ymax: -68.92996` with 65160 polys. Which suggest a fair amount of overplotting. Did you plot that first getH3_poly? Takes a while of course. But it looks as though st_wrap is doing what's expected, as hexes extend to both sides of center (presumed to be dateline), whereas first plots hexes left of center (twice, above and below). Then it's figuring out which polys you need. Or so it seems.

Comment: `length(unique(pts2_H3_poly$h3_address))
[1] 122`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just exploring some thoughts on creation of a smaller example, getting a better bbox, but still haven't addressed st_wrap_dateline:

```
pts2 <- data.frame(merge(seq(-90,90,10),seq(0,360,10), all = TRUE))
colnames(pts2) <- c('LAT', 'LON')
pts_ <- st_as_sf(x = pts2, coords = c('LON', 'LAT'), crs=4326)
pts_H3 <- point_to_h3(pts_, res = 0, simple = FALSE)
pts_H3_poly <- h3_to_polygon(pts_H3$h3_resolution_0, simple = FALSE)
some_idx <- sapply(unique(pts_H3_poly$h3_address), function(i) which(pts_H3_poly$h3_address %in% i))
pts_poly_122 <- pts_H3_poly[unlist(unname(sapply(some_idx, `[[`, 1))), ]
pts_poly_122
Simple feature collection with 122 features and 2 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -179.6744 ymin: -87.3647 xmax: 179.2172 ymax: 87.3647
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
First 10 features:
        h3_address h3_resolution                       geometry
1  80f3fffffffffff             0 POLYGON ((-179.6744 -73.310...
2  80effffffffffff             0 POLYGON ((-34.4418 -87.3647...
3  80e7fffffffffff             0 POLYGON ((48.29116 -69.3713...
4  80ddfffffffffff             0 POLYGON ((-7.138629 -66.192...
5  80d1fffffffffff             0 POLYGON ((4.435671 -35.7412...
6  80c1fffffffffff             0 POLYGON ((-15.54273 -23.004...
8  8099fffffffffff             0 POLYGON ((-11.66475 -4.4670...
10 8075fffffffffff             0 POLYGON ((-4.013998 11.5453...
11 8059fffffffffff             0 POLYGON ((-2.483865 22.1975...
13 8039fffffffffff             0 POLYGON ((-12.38413 40.8691...
```

which is, admittedly, not all that useful but for plotting faster. And bbox is closer to intended.
Then give this a whirl with:

```
pts_poly_122_wrap2 <- st_wrap_dateline(pts_poly_122, options= c('WRAPDATELINE=YES', 'DATELINEOFFSET=20'))
plot(pts_poly_122_wrap2)
```

The choice of 'DATELINEOFFSET=20' was just to be off/different from default, and is that closer to what you were expecting?

Comment: @peter that is perfect! So the DATELINEOFFSET 20 is the piece. That is exactly what I was expecting! THanks so much a huge relief!! Brilliant all the best - thanks Bevan

Comment: thanks for this - still need to work out how to wrap around the entire globe seamlessly which I think is going to be challenging around the pole. Not sure where I got peter from!! Thanks

Comment: I was curious what this would look like, try `mapview::mapview(pts_poly_122_wrap2)`, then experiment with variations of DATELINEOFFSET=10,20,30 etc to see the impact on hexes at edges. I think you might find `h3jsr` requirement of csr=4326 restricting, as you might want to explore other projections that could be arrived at under `sf` stack alone. Ultimately depends on what you're chasing.